# new ajax request on scroll down

Tags: javascript

this is my jQuery

```
$('#banner').click(function (){
            $('#dropdown_c').toggle();

            //ajax request
        function recall(){ setTimeout(function () {  

                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

                xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/ajax/not_data.php", true);

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

                        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                                document.getElementById('dropdown_c').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                            }       
                    }

                xmlhttp.send();
                document.getElementById('dropdown_c').innerHTML = "<img class='non_auto' id='ajax_loading' src='img/ajax_loading.gif'></img>";

                recall();

                }, 2000);
            }; 

                recall();

                function yHandler () {
```

when user scrollc the div...

```
            var dropdown_c = document.getElementById('dropdown_c');
            var contentHeight = dropdown_c.offsetHeight;
            var yOffset = window.pageYOffset;
            var y = yOffset + window.innerHeight;

            if(y >= contentHeight) {
                //new ajax request
                }
            }
            var dropdown_c = document.getElementById('dropdown_c');
            dropdown_c.onscroll  = yHandler;
    });
```

how can i call a new ajax request every time user scrolls down ?

this is not_data.php

```
<?php

$name_query=mysql_query("SELECT name FROM  names);
        while($run_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($name_query)) {
            $name = $run_query['name'];

            echo $name;
}
?>
```

i want to call a new ajax request and get a new name from table `names` everytime user scrolls down

Comment: please try lazy loading plugin

Comment: idk answer bt got syntax error on "not_data.php" page $name_query=mysql_query("SELECT name FROM  names");

Answer (score 1):

You can use .scroll for this purpose. This will get called after every scroll event.

```
  $(window).scroll(function() {
     $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "not_data.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(res){
            alert(name);
        }
    });
  });
```

Comment: so you want to make db communication for every scroll, right?

Comment: Making a new SQL request and new AJAX connection on every (extremely frequent!) scroll event will be awfully resource-heavy (and introduce responsivity delays). Consider the first scroll event to trigger a request to pre-fetch some 20 results, and reach out for another 20 as soon as about 15th is "used up" so that they are already delivered at about the time the user reaches the end of the list.